# GitLab - Write-Host: command not found

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have the following GitLab CI yml file:

```
stages:
  - build
  
CodeQuality:
  stage: build
  image: 
    name: "mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest"
  script:
    - Write-Host "Do your build here, z1234."
```

The pipelines fails with this error:

```
/usr/bin/bash: line 105: Write-Host: command not found
```

In a different SO question, a similiar error message is shown and one comment mentions that the docker container does not have PowerShell installed. Therefore, I added the `image` property but it still fails.
I also tried to use

```
- powershell "Write-Host 'Do your build here, z1234.'"
```

or this

```
- powershell -Command "Write-Host 'Do your build here with PAM.'"
```

but then I only got this error:

```
$ powershell -Command "Write-Host 'Do your build here with PAM.'"
/usr/bin/bash: line 110: powershell: command not found
```

but this also did not recognize the command `powershell`.

What else am I missing?

Comment: Can you modify your yml and add this line :  powershell -Command "Write-Host 'Do your build here, z1234.'"

Comment: @PowerCat, I have updated my question with your suggestion but I got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which shell is configured in your runner but it seems commands in your example are executed in `bash` or `sh` context.

In the image you use Powershell core `pwsh` is available to execute Powershell command.

This script part works :

```
script:
- pwsh -Command "Write-Host "Do your build here, z1234.""
```